# SYSCS_BACKUP_DATABASE and EntityManager/ Backup with JPA

Tags: java, sql, jpa, derby

How to do an [online derby backup](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.0/manuals/admin/hubprnt43.html#HDRSII-BUBBKUP-63476) using the EntityManager (also using JPA) ?

My recent code is not working properly.

```
StoredProcedureQuery query = em.createStoredProcedureQuery("SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_BACKUP_DATABASE");
        query.registerStoredProcedureParameter(1, java.lang.String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
        query.setParameter(1, "pathToDBBackup");
        query.execute();
```

The Error I get is the following.

```
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: The exception 'java.lang.ClassCastException: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException cannot be cast to java.lang.RuntimeException' was thrown while evaluating an expression.
Error Code: 20000
Call: CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_BACKUP_DATABASE(?)
    bind => [1 parameter bound]
Query: ResultSetMappingQuery()
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:340)
    at ...
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: The exception 'java.lang.ClassCastException: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException cannot be cast to java.lang.RuntimeException' was thrown while evaluating an expression.
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at ... 
Caused by: org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException: The exception 'java.lang.ClassCastException: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException cannot be cast to java.lang.RuntimeException' was thrown while evaluating an expression.
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.Statement.completeExecute(Unknown Source)
    at ...
Caused by: org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException: Java exception: 'java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException cannot be cast to java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassCastException'.
    ...
```

Comment: I think the ClassCastException might be a bug in the Derby client driver. You could log a Derby bug for that.

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you specify the complete path to an existing directory as the argument to the procedure?

The NoSuchFileException points in that direction.